# rich text editing, prevent embeded javascript code

Tags: javascript, xss, markdown, csrf, richtextediting

I made a website using the famous symfony framework. I wanted to add rich editing feature to it. And I found TinyMCE editor. But there comed a problem: how about the user embed some javascript code into the content? such as alert('hello world').

I tested wordpress, which is a very famous blog software. It faces the same problem. [example](http://peterlong.info/wordpress-xss-attack-test/).

It is no big deal if some one embed an alert script. But what if they embed some dangerous code? Have you encountered the same problem? Should I use markdown instead of html? Any good widget for markdown editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't allow any embedded javascript in your user input. This is easy to clean out either on the client or the server. Have a "white list" of HTML tags you support, and remove any event listener attributes from whatever you do allow.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good idea to use an existing library to clean out your user input, the html purifier project: http://htmlpurifier.org/ seems maintained and well made.